# Defined integral as the limit of a Riemann sum is not always zero

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I am first learning calculus and my mathematics notation lingo is not the best. I read that the defined integral could be written as the limit of a Riemann sum. Thus:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,\mathrm dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_{i})\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)
$$

My question is, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, why doesn't $\dfrac{b-a}{n}$ equal zero, making the equation always equal to zero?

Comment: Recall the way that the area of a circle was developed in middle school. By cutting a circle into a number of wedges, and then rearranging into a rectangle we found that the area approached $\frac{1}{2}$ the circumference times the radius. As the number of wedges became arbitrarily large, the approximation become even better, even though the area of each wedge came arbitrarily close to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not exactly what the definition is. The limit should be

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$
 i.e., you are summing over $n$ elements. Sure, each of the summands becomes smaller and smaller, but the **number** of the summands increases at the same rate, so the sum will not always be zero.

In fact, take a look at what happens when $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. In that case,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n 1\cdot\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((b-a)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}((b-a)\cdot 1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(b-a)=b-a\neq 0\end{align}$$

---

Also, a further word of warning not entirely on topic, but related to your question:

**If** the Riemann integral of a function over an interval $[a,b]$ exists, then the integral is equal to $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right).$$

However, the existance of the limit above does **not**, in itself, guarantee that a function is Riemann integrable. There exist functions for which

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

exists, but $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ *does not exist*.